# Inkscape words too close together in pdf_tex export

Tags: line-breaking, inkscape, gap

I'd like to have the following text written in Inkscape and exported to pdf_tex:

```
erfasste
Regelgröße $x_{\mathrm{r}}$
```

But the result after running the pdf_tex in Texmaker looks like this:

[image]

Why is there no free space between the 2 lines?

**EDIT**: The text written in the Inkscape-file looks like this:
[image]

It is one single text block. And I'd like to do this with the following code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{normalsize}
        \import{drawing.pdf_tex}
    \end{normalsize}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My directory order:

- main.tex
- IMG

  - drawing.pdf_tex
  - drawing.pdf
- TEX

  - chap.tex

And the code is written in the `chap.tex` file which is included by `main.tex`.

This is my `pdf_tex` file:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape 1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07), www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'Struktur_Regelkreis_3.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{145.83385778bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.17768981)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(-0.00140624,0.12063649){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{0}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}erfasste\\Regelgröße\textit{ $x_{\mathrm{r}}$}\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I updated the answer using your directory setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Inkscape 1.1` and your code I got the following
`drawing.pdf_tex`

```
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{414.74844856bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.1631104)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(-0.0039783,0.10777583){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}erfasste\\Regelgröße $x_{\mathrm{r}}$\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

from copy/past using the  **A**| tool

[image: xxx]

With `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3)`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}    
    \input{drawing.pdf_tex}     
\end{document}
```

the result is correct

[image: a]

The output is typeset as

```
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
        erfasste\\Regelgröße $x_{\mathrm{r}}$
    \end{tabular}
```

with a `\baselineskip`  slightly increased from 12pt to 12.5pt.

**UPDATE**

You need to add the packages `color` and  `import`.

In my system the file `drawing.pdf_tex` is in the same directory of `main.tex` so I used

```
\import{./}{drawing.pdf_tex}
```

In general  `\import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}`

**II** Using your directory structure:

[image: t]

this is `main.tex`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{xcolor}% needed <<< 
\usepackage{import} % needed <<<

\begin{document}    
\input{./TEX/chap}
\end{document}
```

And this is `chap.tex`

```
%% file chap.tex
\chapter{ONE}

 Some text
 
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{normalsize}
    \import{./IMG/}{drawing.pdf_tex}
\end{normalsize}
\end{figure}
```

Produces

[image: b]

Comment: Thats strange. I'm using the same version. How does your text look like in Inkscape? Mine is shown above in edit.

Comment: Where have you saved your pdf_tex-file? In the same directory as your tex-file?

Comment: @Domi1908 maybe you have some other code in your main document that changes tabular distances? Just like with your previous question, it would be useful if you show an MWE that inputs the pdf_tex file, in order to rule out any possible effects from the surrounding code.

Comment: @Domi1908 I copy/pasted your two lines in Inkscape without any change. The pdf_tex file is in the same directory of the main.tex. Compare your pdf_tex file with mine. They should be the same. Then test using my example (the two files) as it is.

Comment: I'm using `\import`. Is that a problem?

Comment: I already use the packages `xcolor` and `import`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It worked for me with copy/past as you said.

Comment: @Domi1908 Thank you for your feedback!